# My answer to a question was deleted, how do I find out why?

Tags: support, feature-request

I currently have four deleted answers, three of them by me(sorry about that, but I think they were generating bad comments) and I noticed the fourth one today

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233926/how-to-apply-css-styling-to-all-but-two-divs/36238710#36238710

I am not saying I have any issue with it being deleted, but I kind of was intrigued that I wasn't able to view my own answer, albeit to someone else's question.

As it stands, I'd like to find out this answer and why it was deleted. If I remember correctly I was looking for an answer in which I explain styles and attributes syntax, and I don't think that answer had anything offensive.

If possible, I'd also like to propose that an answerer should be able to view(even if not vote to undelete) their own answers.

Comment: The entire question was deleted with the reason "RemoveAbandonedClosed" see the help center for more information about that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Comment: @Rizier123 So the question kind of rotted and died. A shame.